# Data retrieval performance among HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap

There are 3 HashMap(say A, B, C). A has 10k elements, B has 1k elements, and C has 500 elements. But the initial 3 elements have similar keys in all 3 Hashmap (say Id(as Key), 100,200,300 common in all 3 Map). I want to retrieve the record for id 200 from all 3 Maps which one will be faster and Why?

**Note:**- This question was asked me in one of my Technical interviews, so if any constraint I am missing please add accordingly?

Comment: I replied all 3 HashMap will take the same time as Key(i.e. 200)  is similar in all 3 Map so if Hash produced similar so bucket location will be same in all 3 Map and it will take same amount of time. Maybe I am wrong but this is what I replied and curious to know what is correct answer. Kindly Help

Comment: HashMap retrieval is **ammortized** O(1) - which means on average you'll get O(1) access & hence the same for all maps. However, with bigger maps there is a higher chance that the bucket selected after hashing might be a bit full so access might be a bit slower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java-with-examples/

The time complexity of HashMap:

HashMap provides constant time complexity for basic operations, get and put if the hash function is properly written and it disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

This is what mentioned in geeksforgeeks article about HashMap. So, I think you have answered correctly.